# producer-consumer Pipeline problem implementation in asyncio

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, producer-consumer, data-mining

I wrote this code to make a non-blocking manager along with pipeline operations using asyncio, my main concern is to catch received items producer, and when the received operation is complete. I want to return all together and merged if keys matches, however, I have a doubt where should I have to join the data at the end producer or consumer in my case that the current workflow is the following

1 - scrape all databases ( multiples clients) (simulate)

2 - pushes to manager (proxy level server) where multiples clients send its data to the manger

3 - Merge multiple data sources into one list as per incoming data no DB operations yet example `{"ID-2002-0201": {"id":"ID-2002-0201","updated_at":"2018-05-14T22:25:51Z","html_url":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}}` > maybe producer

4 - use a get_or_create ( check in the database if there isnt a record with that data , otherwise create it) > consumer

5 - create a bulk of data (maybe chunk the data into smaller chunks to be scalable when growing data source from 2 to 100+) > consumer

server.py

```
# #!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import logging
import random
from pipeline_async import Pipeline

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        return {"ID-2002-0201":{"id":"ID-2002-0201","updated_at":"2018-05-14T22:25:51Z","html_url":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}}

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        return {"ID-2002-0202":{"id":"ID-2002-0202","updated_at":"2018-05-14T22:25:51Z","html_url":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}}

class Manager:

    async def producer(self, pipeline, data_sources):
        """Pretend we're getting a number from the network."""
        for data_stream in data_sources:
            await pipeline.set_message(data_stream.run(), "Producer")
            logging.info("Producer got message: %s", data_stream)

    async def consumer(self, pipeline):
        """ Pretend we're saving a number in the database. """
        while True:
            # wait for an item from the Producer
            message = await pipeline.get_message("Consumer")
            # process the msg
            logging.info(
                "Consumer storing message: %s", message
            )
            # simulate i/o operation using sleep
            await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
            pipeline.task_done()

    async def start(self):
        pipeline = Pipeline()
        data_sources = [A(),B()]
        # schedule the consumer
        consume = asyncio.ensure_future(self.consumer(pipeline))
        # run the producer and wait for completion
        await self.producer(pipeline, data_sources)
        # wait until the consumer has processed all items
        await pipeline.join()
        # the consumer is still awaiting for an item, cancel it
        consume.cancel()
        logging.info("Successfully shutdown the service.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(Manager().start())
```

pipeline.py

```
class Pipeline(asyncio.Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(maxsize=10)

    async def get_message(self, name):
        logging.debug("%s:about to get from queue", name)
        value = await self.get()
        logging.debug("%s:got %s from queue", name, value)
        return value

    async def set_message(self, value, name):
        logging.debug("%s:about to add %s to queue", name, value)
        await self.put(value)
        print(name, value)
        logging.debug("%s:added %s to queue", name, value)
```

I would appreciate some feedback on cases I missed